# Ask about "as ~ as"

Tags: grammar, meaning, grammaticality-in-context

which one is correct and used by most people?

> 1. " There are few things quite as sweet as revenge. "
> 2. " there's no as sweet thing as revenge"

Answer (score 1):

Definitely first one.

> 1. " There are few things quite as sweet as revenge. "

If you want to use it in a negative way

> "Nothing as sweet as revenge."